# protobuf-net : how to represent inheritance in messages and generate derived classes?

Tags: c#, code-generation, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, subtype

`protobuf-net proto2 c#`

Here is my `.cs` file that works for `protobuf-net` serialize/deserialize :

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"MyBaseTypeProto")]
[ProtoBuf.ProtoInclude(typeof(MyDerivedType), 1)]
public partial class MyBaseType { ... }

[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"MyDerivedTypeProto")] 
public partial class MyDerivedType : MyBaseType { ... }

[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"MyMessageProto")]                                                                  
public partial class MyMessage                                          
{                                                                                               
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name = @"MyList", DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]                                                 
    public List<MyDerivedType> MyList;
```

Is it possible to compose `.proto` files so that `protogen.exe` will generate the above ?

Something like :

```
MyBaseType.proto
message MyBaseType {
    ...
}

MyDerivedType.proto
message MyDerivedType {
    ...
}

MyMessage.proto
import "MyDerivedType.proto"
message MyMessage{                                                                          
    repeated MyDerivedType MyList = 1;                                                          
}
```

but `protogen.exe` applied to the above message-types will not generate the above classes as desired; specifically it will not generate these lines of code :

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoInclude(typeof(MyDerivedType), 1)]

public partial class MyDerivedType : MyBaseType
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protocol buffers doesn't support inheritance in a form that's analogous to (or maps to) intuitive inheritance in C++/C#/Java.

See [here](http://www.indelible.org/ink/protobuf-polymorphism/):

> Messages can also be extended, but the method by which this is accomplished differs from familiar C++ or Java-style inheritance. Instead, message extension is implemented by reserving some number of field indices in the base message for use by the extending messages.

And the [protocol buffer docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#extensions) say:

> Extensions let you declare that a range of field numbers in a message are available for third-party extensions. Other people can then declare new fields for your message type with those numeric tags in their own .proto files without having to edit the original file.

The first article also discusses several other techniques for approximating polymorphism, with the pros and cons of each.

Comment: so `protobuf` spec is saying to support class structures with inheritance , `message type defs` should reserve a range of `field indexes` to satisfy all potential sub-classing needs : in this manner, messages make use of composition "inside" to support inheritance "outside". but how to overcome the shortcoming that because in the "sub-class" message all fields are notated as equal members, `protogen.exe` is incapable of generating derived classes that properly notate their base class ?

Comment: Rather than overcome, I think you must adapt.  Think about your problem differently, so it doesn't require inheritance in the message classes.  You might have inheritance in your own classes, which wrap and/or determine how to parse, messages.